# iphone child view inside rows on a for() statment in JS, appcelerator

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium, appcelerator

I'm making an iPhone app in appcelerator where students can see their classes schedule.

I have a JSON response where it brings me the classrooms with these attributes:

- day
- hour
- class
- professor

So an example would be an array having something like this:

`[monday,8:00,math,sofia heelter]`

`[monday,10:00,biology,andrea sulivan]`

`[friday,8:00,math,sofia heelter]`

---

I receive those parameters and show them in a `UITableView` with this code:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < response.classrooms.lenght; i++)
        {
        var day= response.classrooms[i].day;
        var hour= response.classrooms[i].hour;
        var materia= response.classrooms[i].class;
        var professor= response.classrooms[i].professor;

            var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({height:'auto'});
            var post_view = Titanium.UI.createView({
                height:'auto', 
                layout:'vertical',
                top:5,
                right:5,
                bottom:5,
                left:5
            });
            var text= Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                text:text,

                top:0,
                left:0,
                bottom:15,
                height:48,
                width:300,
                font:{fontFamily:'helvetica',fontSize:20}
            });
            post_view.add(text);
            // Add the post view to the row
            row.add(post_view);
            // Give each row a class name
            row.className = "item"+i;
            // Add row to the rowData array
            rowData[i] = row;

        }
```

So the question is this...

How can I assign to each class (I mean the university classroom that is shown above) which is in a row to have a child?

So when I click on the rows it brings up a child view with the info regarding their classrooms. I have the info about the classroom I just want to assign a child to every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should set hasChild property for the row view to show that row has child.

```
var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({height:'auto',hasChild:true});
```

Then you can open a new [window](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Window-object), or [view](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.View-object) to show the details of the data and it should be handle in your tableview click event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here, first off, you do not want to have a different className for each row, it should be the same for all of the rows.

```
 // Give each row a class name
 row.className = "studentRowClass";
```

Secondly to show specific information about a class room, BTW I dont see any classroom information in the code provided above, you would just pass it as a property to the row like this

```
row.classRoomInfoURL = "class_one.js"
```

when handling the eventListener for the row

```
table.addEventListener('click', function(eventData) {
Ti.API.debug(eventData);
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:"CLASS ROOM INFO",
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    width:'100%',
    height:'100%',
    url: eventData.rowData.classRoomInfoURL,
});
win.open();
```

});